# Angularjs - set limit on user choice in a select field

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to build a method to limit the user choice in a couple of select fields. Below is a sample and here is a jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/18414/

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <select size="5" id="selectpicker1" multiple ng-model="params.monthly" ng-change="selectionChanged(params.monthly)">
     <option ng-repeat="month in newMonthlyArray">{{month}}</option>
  </select>

</div>
```

Controller:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

//myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
//myApp.factory('myService', function() {});

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'Superhero';

    //console.log('YES');
    $scope.newMonthlyArray = ["2015-Jan", "2015-Feb", "2015-Mar", "2015-Apr"];
    $scope.selectionChanged = function (data) {
        if (data.length > 2) {
            alert('You can choose 2 months');
        }
    }

}
```

The part I'm having issues with is to remove the last chosen option and update the `$scope` variable. I can do with JQuery but didn't want to create a hybrid solution.

Any ideas will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really have to do that much to remove the extra selected elements:

```
if(data.length > 2){
    data.splice(2);
    //alert('You can choose 2 months');
}
```

Basically, that's all you need: `data` is your `ng-model="params.monthly"`
and since this model is bound to the select element, Angular will do the rest to update it:

http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/18420/

EDIT: As @Metallica suggested, not in all cases the select element is updated by Angular.

The only way to provide visual feedback, is to manually update the DOM:

```
if(data.length > 2) {
    data.splice(2);
    var selected = select.querySelectorAll('option:checked');
    angular.forEach(selected, function(s) {
        if(data.indexOf(s.value) < 0) s.selected = false;
    });
}
```

In the updated example `select` is `$element[0].querySelector('select')`
the select element in this controller.

The additional code is to:

- get all selected option elements and
- iterate over the elements and check if they are present in the model data and update the `selected` property accordingly

Updated fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/18422/

Comment: If you don't want to deselect the extra selected options, sure, this is ture. But since the OP wants to deselect those (as a visual feedback probably), I think you need to go through the options and deselect extra stuff.

Comment: @Metallica You are right, I was just briefly testing the example and for some cases Angular updates the select element according to the model. I will look at this later. In an normal case, you don't have to update the DOM by yourself and Angular is doing this based on the model data.

Answer (score 2):

You can get a reference to the extra selected items in your select element and deselect those items. In your `selectionChanged` method, iterate over options in your select element, deselect invalid selections, and update your model (`data` which is a reference to `params.monthly`).

```
angular.forEach(document.getElementById("selectpicker1").options, function(item) {
  if (data.length > 2 && item.selected) {
    data.splice(2);
    item.selected = false;
  }
});
```

You can use $watch service to make things easier and delete your own watch method (`selectionChanged`):

```
$scope.$watch(function() {
  // In this function, return whatever object/value you would like to observe. 
  // This function is invoked whenever there is a change to the specified value/obj
  return document.getElementById("selectpicker1").options;
}, function (items) {
  // The argument of this function holds the new value of what you return in the 
  // first function. Feel free to name it whatever you wish
  angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
    var data = $scope.params.monthly;
    if (data.length > 2 && item.selected) {
      data.splice(2);
      item.selected = false;
      alert('You can choose 2 months');
    }
  });
});
```

Usually you need to clean/unregister your watch function, but in this case, you don't need to, because no other method/function relies on the value of your select element.

Comment: I updated my solution but it's now more or less exactly what you have posted: +1. I was also trying to use `ng-selected="model.indexOf(value) > -1"` on the option element which surprisingly sets the selected property but visually the remains selected.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ng-options`. See my [fork](http://jsfiddle.net/fpinheiro/tb8h3s0n/)

```
<select (...) ng-options="month for month in newMonthlyArray">
```

And in the controller, remove the last selected (using [lodash](https://lodash.com/)):

```
if(data.length > 2){
  alert('You can choose 2 months');
  data = _.pull(data, _.last(data))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your controller:

```
$scope.onSelect = function() {
    var selected = this.month;
    $scope.newMonthlyArray.splice($scope.newMonthlyArray.indexOf(selected), 1);
};
```

and this to your  tag:

```
<option ng-click="onSelect()" ...
```